# The advantages and disadvantages of using ORM

Tags: orm

I would like to discuss the advantages and disadvantages of using ORM (such as ADO.NET).

### Advantages:

- Speeds-up Development - eliminates the need for repetitive SQL code.
- Reduces Development Time.
- Reduces Development Costs.
- Overcomes vendor specific SQL differences - the ORM knows how to write vendor specific SQL so you don't have to.

### Disadvantages:

- Loss in developer productivity whilst they learn to program with ORM.
- Developers lose understanding of what the code is actually doing - the developer is more in control using SQL.
- ORM has a tendency to be slow.
- ORM fail to compete against SQL queries for complex queries.

In summary, I believe that the advantages of using an ORM (mainly the reduced time taken to perform repetitive tasks) are far outweighed by the disadvantages of ORM e.g. it's difficulty to get to grips with.

Can people point out where I am going wrong and suggest any further advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: ADO.NET itself is not an "ORM".

Comment: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." The absence of the former precludes the latter. If your opinion is that a question will solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion should it not first be proven that any answers to the question must inherently lack facts, references, and expertise? The burden of proof is on the closer of the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> "ORM fail to compete against SQL
>   queries for complex queries."

- Well both LINQ-SQL and Entity Framework Allow complex queries and even translation of SQL query results into objects.

> "Developers loose understanding of
>   what the code is actually doing - the
>   developer is more in control using
>   SQL."

- Not really, if you know what you are doing. SQL profiler is enough to see what the translated SQL queries are.

> "ORM has a tendency to be slow."

- Yes, but delay loading and some smart options can make it almost as fast.

> "Loss in developer productivity whilst
>   they learn to program with ORM."

- Hibernate and the Entity Framework might take time to learn but in the long run they will save time in development. LINQ-SQL on the other hand has little to no learning curve involved.

I say, use ORM but keep this in mind.

1. Design your queries and write code
   that will result in the least number
   of roundtrips with the server. It's
   the overhead taken for the roundtrip
   that takes up time.
2. Read about the experiences other
       people have had with the selected
       ORM before you dig in too deep.
3. Always compare your queries with the
           actual ones being executed in SQL
           server profiler.

**Edit:**
You wouldn't use an ORM for a performance critical situation same way you wouldn't use .Net or Java to write an operating system. Consider your requirements before choosing. Even if you don't use an ORM, you will end up doing some mapping yourself either via repeating a lot of code or by using a data dictionary. Why not use an ORM and know how to use its options to make it ALMOST as fast? Weigh up the advantages and disadvantages and make your choice.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.ca/2012/06/when-should-i-use-orm.html

Comment: Regarding "Always compare your queries with the actual ones being executed", that defeats the whole purpose of using ORM in the first place.

Comment: No it doesn't. The purpose of an ORM isn't just to make queries. You have to check queries to see whether they are the converted to the most efficient form or else tweak your ORM query as needed. Also most ORM's support direct SQL query result translation to Entities. Don't expect not to know SQL and use CRUD even with an ORM unless it's very simple project.

Comment: Indeed that's the whole purpose of ORMs: for very simple projects with no bottlenecks anywhere. When you get to the point where *"You have to check queries to see whether they are the converted to the most efficient form or else tweak your ORM query as needed"*, it **defeats the whole purpose** of using ORM in the first place, because the purpose of using ORM is to avoid exactly that.

Comment: Look I think you need to do a bit more research in to ORM's if you think the "the whole purpose of ORM" is to make queries. I can tell you that Hibernate and Entity Framework power more than "very simple projects". A bit more reading might help you there too. Have a read here http://java.dzone.com/articles/martin-fowler-orm-hate

End of the day ORM helps you design better models and separates the persistence layer in such a way that you spend FAR less time writing highly coupled boilerplate code and come up with better models. Not to forget that you can target multiple DBMS at once.

Comment: "hack up some simple app that doesn't need any db performance."  - Categorically false. You probably haven't had enough experience in using them in a big project at all. Look in to Delay loading techniques and query translation before coming up with personal opinion as fact. If the whole purpose of ORM is not to "touch" queries at all then how come all major ORM's support querying either via their own language or SQL and translation to object. If you have something more to add please add it as an answer and see how many people accept it. No point continuing this as comments. That is all.

Comment: You can't add an answer to a question that's closed. And yes, back to ORM again, ORM is only used for hacking up some simple app that doesn't need any db performance. It's your definition of "big" and "db heavy" that needs revising. **Name** me some big db-heavy projects using ORM to solve their persistent needs. Yes, the whole purpose of ORM is not to touch queries at all. So you ask *"Why ORM's support querying via SQL"*. Indeed, that's what I've been saying right from the.............................................................................‌​........

Comment: ............................................................first comment and Yes, you're starting to see the light. Is [the answer](http://goo.gl/kvQGMz) not plain obvious enough? I guess it's not to people buried too deep into ORM, so allow me to explain why ORMs **must** allow raw SQL: **Because [the abstraction](http://goo.gl/phoKE1) is [leaky](http://goo.gl/FivDle)**. They realize that their brainchild only works for the simple use cases and now they have two options, **1**: Throw the baby out, or **2**: Give people the ability to **ignore ORM** and do raw SQL. Guess which they've chosen?

Comment: Some of the BIG ERP projects I've been involved in uses ORMs. Namely the new MYOB Advanced which is the most recent. Things that have 600+ tables and have 100 concurrent users with good throughput. Your argument would the same for Java/.Net vs C/C++ because the high level languages aren't in native code and has performance issues. But how many ERP's are written in C? Sure plain old SQL will give you a faster result. No one is arguing that. But most times the the performance gain is **Inconsequential** compared to an ORM query done right. ........................

Comment: The problem isn't with the ORM mostly but developers who have little experience using them writing queries that populate the entire object graph, not using delay/deffered loading or have tracking enabled when not required. You conveniently forget the fact that any OOP solution that interacts with db has some ORM. Be it a known one or a custom one done by the developer. **Let go of the notion that ORM's are a clear abstraction** ORM's help us write less code and do more in a organized way. 1. For Add/Edit/Delete operations ORM can be used to maximum effect ..............

Comment: ............... 2. For querying data ORM's should be used carefully depending on how you plan to use the result. If you don't plan to use objects and only want to display a report or a view to the user just use the SQL query or anonymous type options of the ORM. 

Using an ORM is won't magically make SQL go away. You are stuck in definitions.Leaky or not ORM's is a great way to develop more standardized uniform code (while still having access to direct SQL).  Your original argument that looking at queries making ORM's obsolete is **only** valid if for your definition of what an ORM should be.

Comment: Database vendor independence and “Hiding SQL”
These are just additional benefits you can get but they are not the main purpose of an ORM tool. ... Quoted from http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/04/20/orm-is-not-a-choice.html

Comment: For a list of pro and contra arguments (**that both of us keep repeating**) have a read here with some good links architects.dzone.com/articles/high-complexity-and-low **If you have further comments let's create a new topc with your argument about queries.** We are just regurgitating the same thing now. Allow other people to contribute different ideas.

Comment: Every programming abstraction is leaking something. Unless you want to build systems with machine code abstractions are a part of life for developers. While I agree some are leakier than others it boils down to the understanding of the developer. The issue here is your *full abstraction* expectation which will never be satisfied with any programming abstraction namely MVC, ORM, OOP or Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the requirement, you might want to choose to use or not ORM.
For example: Multiple persistence engine support (need to run on Oracle, DB2, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), you might benefit from the abstraction that you get from ORM at the cost of potential app performance lost.

If you know that you are going to only support a particular persistence engine and you want to be able to take advantage of a particular feature in the persistence engine that might not be supported in the ORM, well... clear enough which choice you should choose.

Another factor might be developer knowledge like you mentioned and the time to learn the new stuffs and the actual project time (hard deadline, etc.).  This goes for both staffs that know a particular ORM already versus staffs that does not know ORM but excel in ADO.NET / any other lower level data access technology.