# Reasons to use a persistence framework in Java EE?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a Java EE Application, and I use Spring as framework.
Now I've seen people talking about ORM Frameworks (Hibernate/JPA/iBatis...) but I don't know what might be the reasons to use those frameworks?

I mean what those frameworks will change in the project functions & performance?

if you can give me a clear example it will be great.

Comment: First of all, it is not "now..people talking about ORM".It has been here for years. Refer to
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667906/the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-orm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will get bored by writing the SQL insert/update/select statements for entire java objects and keep the Object <-> SQL code in shape when your object changes. JPA is actually a part of the Java EE standard.

However, it will **not** provide any means to keep you from knowing what you are doing with the database, except for very simple cases. My experience is that any JPA framework will add just another layer of complexity to performance issue track down and debugging.

In the end, you might end up need to understand how JPQL (SQL-ish syntax for JPA) translate into SQL for every combination of JPA provider (OpenJPA, HIbernate, eclipse link..) and datbase implementation. This will be non trivial.

If you have no specific performance requirements and just want easy object persistance, give it go! Hibernate seems to be state of the art atm.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing your own SQL for everything, and to [partially] bridge the object-relational gulf ("abyss").

For simple requirements, ORMs are great, and make thinking about some DB stuff go away--with the caveat that you still need to be aware of what's actually happening on the DB side to prevent what can be serious performance implications.

For complicated requirements, you'll learn to understand why they call ORMs the "Vietname of computer science"... "We have learned the lessons of Vietnam... do not go to Vietnam."