# Is mapping of data contract to entity of entity framework in wcf is costly operation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

While using EF with wcf come across the condition where i need to map entity to data contract and vice versa because EF objects are burdened with additional data provided by EF. So tried few functions for mapping.

```
[DataContract]
public class WebsitesD
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

private WebsitesD mapWebsite(Website w)
    {
        WebsitesD wd = new WebsitesD();
        wd.Id = w.Id;
        wd.Title = w.Title;
        wd.UserId = w.UserId;
        wd.Domain = w.Domain;
        return wd;
    }
  public int insertWebsite(WebsitesD d)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyInfoEntities entities = new MyInfoEntities())
            {
                entities.Websites.Add(mapWebsite(d));
                entities.SaveChanges();
                return 1;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

where WebsitesD is my data contract and website is entity object. With this i can achieve my objective but problem is that whenever i need to perform any database operation i need to do mapping which i think can be costly operation.

Should i leave Entity Framework and go with ADO .net as i don't need to do any mapping over there. Please suggest me pros and cons with which approach i should go.

Answer (score 0):

As with any ORM there is trade-off between performance and developer productivity. As you said ADO.NET will be the fastest method to fill your data contracts from datareader/dataset, with EF/NHibernate you will always have this situation. However mapping is not expensive for solo entities , it becomes expensive when you map list of entities.If you dont need mapping at all , you can also put [DataContract] on entity classes and [DataMember] on members which wcf want to send to client. but when your EF code is autogenerated when your schema changes , that is all wiped out.
You can also opt for [EF Code First approach.](https://codefirst.codeplex.com/)

Another approach which involves less coding for mapping is to use AutoMapper 
[Check this out](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Also there is good thread on ORM tradeoffs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667906/the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Do what's best for the code base. Consider maintainability and productivity. Servers are cheap and developers are expensive. Very few companies in the world are of such a scale that it is worth maintaining more complicated code rather than buying another server.

Answer (score 0):

With EF 6, you can use the code generation item **EF 6.x DbContext Generator with WCF Support.**

Just right click on the designer of the EDMX and go to **Add Code Generation Item...**

Click **Online** on the left and search for **DbContext.**

[image: EF 6.x DbContext Generator with WCF Support]

Using this will auto generate the **DataMember** and **DataContract** Attributes in your classes.
Also, you'll probably want to delete the regular template generated with the edmx, or you will have two sets of entities.